# Bookmarklet JS Location doesn't change on second click

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

with the following bookmarklet I want to open a url:

```
javascript:function z() {return 'https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=de&pli=1#dashboard/X-gSslPrQzqUKVo4_jarXg/a3789910asdf263939/%3F_u.date00%3D20140413%26_u.date01%3D20140413%26_.useg%3D/'; } 
window.location = z();
```

It works fine, but on the second time I click on the bookmarklet it is not loading the URL anew, but diplays it. Like it is the HTML content. However it should just load the very same url again.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `window.location.href = z()`?

Comment: No, this doesn't help. It seems like firefox doesnt like it, if i use this bookmarklet twice. :(

Comment: This code does just open a URL. What for you need to do this by bookmarklet? It seems you can bookmark the URL directory.

Comment: The function itself is more complex and working just fine. It takes the latest date and puts it in the url, on the first click the url is opened as I wish.
On the second click the address bar shows "javascript: ..." (my function) and the content (where a website is displayed) is "https://...". If I change to open in "_blank" it also works only on the first click. And in one tab the correct url is opened and in another there is "[Window]" (or something like that) shown as content.